# (php) strpos offset in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, strpos

I'm studying php reading tutorial in this website(http://www.tizag.com/)
Below is the excerpt from the tutorial.

```
<?php
$numberedString="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
$offset=0;
$fiveCounter=0;
echo $numberedString;
if(strpos($numberedString, "5")==0){
    $fiveCounter++;
    echo "<br />Five #$fiveCounter is at position - 0";
}
while($offset=strpos($numberedString, "5", $offset+1)){
    $fiveCounter++;
    echo "<br />Five #$fiveCounter is at position - $offset";
}?>
```

I don't understand how the offset changes.
Shouldn't the code in while() be true? It seems like designating offset.
I understand the first offset is 0. When it goes to

```
while($offset=strpos($numberedString, "5", $offset+1)
```

for the first time, the offset changes into 1 due to '$offset+1'.
Then, I think

```
strops($numberedString, "5", $offset+1)
```

becomes 4.

And I guess 4 becomes offset again, and start the loop again, but
how come the codes in the while() can designate something else?
Shouldn't it be true to output something?

Comment: `the offset changes into 1 due to '$offset+1'` – that does not change the value of `$offset`, it just increments the value that is _passed to `strpos`_ by one.

Answer (score 2):

Hanky's answer is correct, but I'll fill in a few of the details since, judging from the fact that you are working on a tutorial you are trying to learn PHP.

At the beginning of the script, the variable `$offset` is set to 0.The first time the while loop runs (provided a 5 was not identified in position 1 in the if statement proceeding) the offset is incremented by 1 (the `$offset+1` in the the `strpos` function in the while loop) Doing that also is incrementing the $offset variable above. The `strpos` function will return either the position of the next 5 in the string (and thus change the value of the `$offset` variable once again, this time to the newest position of 5) or return false and in effect end the loop execution.

Comment: Nevermind, Hanky's revised answer states it all quite eloquently- if I could up vote it a second time I would.

Answer (score 1):

According to [strops](https://www.php.net/strpos) manual

> **offset**
>
> If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string.

Offset keeps changing because `strops`  returns only the position of first occurrence of your needle `5` and then you tell it to start searching after that position for next iteration, and so on. Offset will keep on changing until `strops` returns that there are no more `5`s available in the string

`$offset+1` is only being used in the loop to tell `strops` to start searching `after` that position which it obtained previously. It doesn't increment your `$offset` variable's value.

See this for a little clarification, (just changed one variable's name)

```
<?php
$numberedString="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
$lastPosition=0;
while($currentPosition=strpos($numberedString, "5", $lastPosition+1)){
    echo "Present at $currentPosition <br>";
    $lastPosition=$currentPosition;
}
?>
```

**Edit**
Infact, you should try this to make it more understandable

```
$numberedString="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
echo "Haystack is ".$numberedString;
$lastPosition=0;
while($currentPosition=strpos($numberedString, "5", $lastPosition+1)){
    echo "\nPresent at $currentPosition and now the haystack will be ".substr($numberedString,$currentPosition);
    $lastPosition=$currentPosition;
}
```

**Output**

```
Haystack is 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Present at 4 and now the haystack will be 567890123456789012345678901234567890
Present at 14 and now the haystack will be 56789012345678901234567890
Present at 24 and now the haystack will be 5678901234567890
Present at 34 and now the haystack will be 567890
```

Comment: while($currentPosition=strpos($numberedString, "5", $lastPosition+1) by this, through the first attempt, current position becomes 4, because strpos($numberedString, "5", $lastPosition+1) becomes 4. Then the code in the while loop 
parenthesis becomes $currentPosition=4. I feel like we are setting $currentPosition is 4. Shouldn't the code in the parenthesis be true? And is the last line, $lastPosition+$currentPositon, saying that we are changing the value of $lastPosition to the value of $currentPosition, which is changing 0 to 4, by the first attempt?

Comment: while($currentPosition=strpos($numberedString, "5", $lastPosition+1) by this, through the first attempt, current position becomes 4, because strpos($numberedString, "5", $lastPosition+1) becomes 4. Then the code in the while loop parenthesis becomes $currentPosition=4. I feel like we are setting $currentPosition is 4. Shouldn't the code in the parenthesis be true? And is the last line, $lastPosition+$currentPositon, saying that we are changing the value of $lastPosition to the value of $currentPosition, which is changing 0 to 4, by the first attempt? –